# IF ELSE function in R studio

Tags: r, if-statement

Can somebody explain why this code results in 1 for input: exam(5)?

```
exam<-function(x){
  y<-1
  if(x==1){
    return(1)
  }
  else{
    return(y*exam(x-1))
    y<-y+1
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally that is not a good question according to StackOverflow's guidelines. But your function, only executes the `else` condition `x-1` times and then lastly the `if` condition one time as `x==1` is true when x becomes 1.

i.e.
For `exam(5)`, following happens:

```
x = 5, y = 1, `else` executed 1 * exam(4)
x = 4, y = 1, `else` executed 1 * 1 * exam(3)
x = 3, y = 1, `else` executed 1 * 1 * 1 * exam(2)
x = 2, y = 1, `else` executed 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * exam(1)
x = 1, y = 1, `if` executed 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1
```

- This results in 1.

The last expression on your `else` statement `y<-y+1`, is never executed because you `return(y*exam(x-1))` before it is evaluated.

Comment: i did not downvote, but I think you got the y=-1 wrong. It is set to 1. Otherwise the logic is correct

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your script slightly

```
exam<-function(x){
  y<-1
  if(x==1){
            print("if x===1")
    return(1)

  }
  else{
        print(paste("x = ",x ))
    return(y*exam(x-1))
    y<-y+1
  }
}
```

now you should be able to see results of each recursive iteration

```
> exam(5)
[1] "x =  5"
[1] "x =  4"
[1] "x =  3"
[1] "x =  2"
[1] "if x===1"
[1] 1
```

Because you have not explained what results do you expect, it is hard to help you any further.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Something is not entirely clear to me yet. Will y not increase by 1 every time x is increased by 1?

Comment: @JillLange check my answer below

Comment: @JillLange it is not because of the placement of `return`. I would recommend you to play more with your code and see what changes in order might bring as a result. Otherwise, try to explain what you are trying to do and what results do you expect. See @dryleaf answer for more detailed explanation what your current code is doing.